# Java Change attribute from driver class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure if my professor mistyped the instruction or I just missed something. I am given an assignment and we're working on arraylist. A part of the instruction ask us to write in the class a method to change an attribute name city, a method called setCity(). After that I will create a driver class to ask users to search for the person who I want to change the city for. My professor replied but it was basically a repeat of the instruction. During the weekend there will be no replies until Monday.

I understand from the driver side how to write this method. But my question is how to write the setCity() method to change the city attribute in the main class?

Quote of the instruction: " Your CityEntry class should have a setCity() method that will allow the city attribute to be changed"

Example:

```
public static void editCity(ArrayList<CityEntry> address){
    boolean found = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("example: ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < address.size(); i++){
        if(address.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(found){
        System.out.println("Enter new city: ");
        //here's the problem. If I should create a method in the driver for setCity()
        //can't think of how to create it in the CityEntry class
    }
}
```

Would an example of setCity() method in the CityEntry class look like this?

```
public String setCity(city){
    this.city = city;
    return city;
}
```

Edit: Thanks everyone. I had forgotten the basics for mutators. We haven't been using it for majority of our assignments. So kind didn't know what the professor meant by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but in this case you don't need to return anything. All you need to do is change the city.

In Java, when we don't want to return anything, we use "void" as the type (the return void part is implied and left out).

So instead of

```
public String setCity(String city){
```

you will use

```
public void setCity(String city){
```

and don't return anything.

Comment: What kind of setter function doesn't have any parameter?!

Comment: The kind that are not terribly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you are going to write this function inside a `CityEntry` class which has this `city` attribute. This attribute most probably will be either `protected` or `private` that's why you need a `setter` (mutator) but your setter method **shouldn't** return anything it just changes the value of the city attribute. To return the value of the `city` attribute, you can also use a `getter` (accessor) methods like following:

```
public class CityEntry {
    //Private fields
    private String city;
    ...

    //Constructor method
    public CityEntry(String city, ...) {
        this.city = city;
        ....
    }

    //Accessor for city
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    //Mutator for city
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

For more information, you can take a look: http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just like the other replies, `setCity()` is a setter method. It doesn't return anything. It is passed the name and it will assign that to the `this.city` instance variable. So basically you need to change `public String setCity()` into `public void setCity(String city)`.